# Image won't show up in html extension in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h1 title="First Heading">Heading 1</h1>
        <h6 title="Second Heading">Heading 2</h6>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p title="First Paragraph">Paragraph 1</p>
        <p title="Second Paragraph">Paragraph 2</p>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp" >W3schools</a>
        <img src="C:\Users\yorda\OneDrive\Gambar\Aseprite\.jpeg\Canyon.jpeg" alt="Pixel Art" width="320" height="180"
    </body>
</html>
```

If I open my html file via file explorer (double clicking it and go to chrome) it will show the image.

[image]

but if I want to preview my html file via VS Code extension the image wont show up.

[image]

why is this happen? any way to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct way to write a file URL is `src="file:///C:/Users/yorda/OneDrive/Gambar/Aseprite/.jpeg/Canyon.jpeg"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the image in the same location of your index.html file.

then modify your img src to

```
<img src="Canyon.jpeg" />
```